# Remove active class from bootstrap navbar links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm coding navbar in bootstrap and I've social media links added on the right side of the navbar, if links are clicked they are opened in a new window. I want to make so social media links would not get active class on a click.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li id="facebook">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></i></a>
    </li>  
    <li id="twitter">
        <a href="#"  target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter"></i></a>
    </li> 
    <li id "google-plus">
        <a href="#"  target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-google-plus"></i></a>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work and I don't know why? link1, would be default active link for that page.

```
<script>
    $(".nav li").click(function() {
        $(".nav li#link1").addClass('active');
        $(".nav li#facebook").removeClass('active');
        $(".nav li#twitter").removeClass('active');
        $(".nav li#google-plus").removeClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can u create fiddle link?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12790/

Comment: could be simplified to `$(".nav li").click(function() {  //add class to link and $(this).removeClass('active')});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
<script>
  $(function(){

    $('.navbar-right li').click(function(){ 
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }); 
  })
</script>
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQpVKm)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<script>
    $(".nav li").click(function() {
       $(".nav li").removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in CSS like,

```
#navbar ul li#facebook a:hover,#navbar ul li#facebook a:active {
    color: #3b5998 !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried this at first, but it didn't work since all you do is change color. Navbar by default thinks that there can be only 1 active link, so after you press another link original active link would lose its status, active color, background, etc.

Comment: do one thing,you do all color changing operations in css only ,comment js once,and for facebook,twiter and google div give common class ,that should have active ,hover  make it as important. and colo check

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
$(".nav li").click(function() {

   $(".nav li a:active").css('display',null);// discard inline style
   $(".nav li a:active").removeClass('active');//remove pseudo class
   $(".nav li#link1").addClass('active');
 });
```